# Passing Values from Different Source Code

Tags: java

Is their any way to get a value from a separate java file ? Ex. If i have Test1.java and Test2.java could I get values from Test1 into Test2 I have tried looking online and cannot find anything about it ... all I find is HTML code tutorials. I hope this is a good enough explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are needing are getters/setters.I hope the following link can answer all you need to know:
[Tutorial](http://java.dzone.com/articles/getter-setter-use-or-not-use)